# Linq Join by ids and sort by name

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say i have 2 collection of objects (I modified example a bit from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
Person magnus = new Person { Name = "Hedlund, Magnus", Id = 1 };
Person terry = new Person { Name = "Adams, Terry", Id =2 };
Person charlotte = new Person { Name = "Weiss, Charlotte", Id = 3 };

Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = 1};
Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = 2};
Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = 2};
Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = 3};

List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte };
List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, daisy };
```

How can I now sort pets by **their owners names** and return collection of pets, i.e. I want the result like:

```
boots, whiskers, barley, daisy.
```

Any ideas? Thx in advance!

Comment: What about `whiskers, boots, barley, daisy`? Is it ordered as you expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = from pet in  pets
            join person in people 
            on pet.Owner equals person.Id
            orderby person.Name
            select pet;
```

**Edit** Since you want a "collection of pets":

```
List<Pet> result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: It should be ordered by the owner's name and not the pet's. I suggest changing `pet.Name` to `person.Name`

Answer (score 3):

```
pets.OrderBy(x => people.First(p => p.Id == x.Owner).Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without `Join` (as Selman22 said), but it can be also done using `Join`:

```
var result = from pet in pets
             join person in people on pet.Owner equals person.Id
             orderby person.Name
             select pet.Name;
```

`Join` version should be faster, especially for collections with many elements.